# isValid() method in owasp html sanitizer

Tags: owasp, html-sanitizing

I have a page in my application where user can enter HTML input. Now in order to avoid XSS attack i am using OWASP HTML Sanitizer to sanitize the user input. If the user input is not valid according to the policy i just want to throw the user out.

is there a way to simple check if the input html is valid against the policy without sanitizing ?

something like

public static boolean isValid(String input, Policy policy);

Answer (score 0):

You can define yourself the `isValid` method but I'm not sure you can do it without calling the sanitize method.

```
// Define the policy factory
PolicyFactory polFac = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
    .allowElements("a", "p")
    .allowAttributes("href").onElements("a")
    .toFactory(); 

boolean isValid(String input, PolicyFactory polFac){
    return input.equals(polFac.sanitize(input));
}
```

You can obtain a more robust version of `isValid`using the second version of the `sanitize`method (in the `PolicyFactory`class) that reports the names of rejected element and attributes.

Comment: fwiw - the maintainer of this project rejects the idea of idempotent validity (input being equal to output indicating validity) for many reasons, one of which being that it's possible for the OWASP HTML sanitizer to do things like change single quotes to double quotes in an `a` tag. There's a much more thorough explanation [here](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/blob/main/docs/html-validation.md).